# How can this circuit be best described?

Tags: diodes, ltspice, rectifier, output, capacitor-charging

[image: Circuit schematic made in LTspice]

[image: Input and Output Waveforms]

Here, the green waveform is the input waveform(V1) and the blue waveform is the potential drop across Vc1 and Vc2.

To me it seems like a peak detector getting clamped, but then the first half cycle and the second half cycle messes that up. Can this circuit be described as some basic electronic circuit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first half-cycle charges C1 so Vc1 goes positive while C2 is still uncharged.

The second half-cycle charges C2 so that Vc2 goes negative. Since Vc1 is still positive the difference between the two is doubled.

The circuit is called "a voltage doubler".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBCRM0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A more usual way of drawing the circuit may look more familiar.*

Comment: Yes, I know that. But my question was that if there is any specific name for this type of circuit?

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a "voltage doubler" circuit.  There are many variations of this but as you can see, that's basically what you get across Vc1 to Vc2.  It's 2X V1's peak.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a voltage multiplier, or more specifically a voltage doubler.